# Vague Error Message in Laravel FileSystem Unlink

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, filesystems, laravel-5.1

Good day,

I modified this file.

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php
```

This is the function I modified.

```
public function handleError($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0, $context = [])
```

I made it send me an email. The email has the $message and the $file and the $line.

This is what the email said.

```
MESSAGE FILE vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php LINE 126
```

The message is blank, but it's running into an error in a file. I open the file.

```
public function delete($paths)
{
    $paths = is_array($paths) ? $paths : func_get_args();

    $success = true;

    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        try {
            if (! @unlink($path)) { # the error is here
                $success = false;
            }
        } catch (ErrorException $e) {
            $success = false;
        }
    }

    return $success;
}
```

I am confused. Why was the error not caught by the catch block? What type of error would not give a message to the error handler of laravel? Is there something I can do to get more information regarding the error?

This is our version of Laravel.

Laravel Framework version 5.1.45 (LTS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the question you have asked is misleading. What you are trying to do is add a custom error handler in laravel which you can achieve by following [this URL](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#custom-monolog-configuration) .

The error you are facing might be caused due to file permission error.

And since there is the **@** sign before the function call unlink() any errors which are caused by it are suppressed.

Remove the **@** sign and if the file doesn't exists or if there is an error it would throw it and then catch block would catch it.

Comment: So even with all the errors suppressed by "@" it is still ending up in  `handleError` ? That is so strange.

Comment: @JonAbaca in short No. When you add the @ symbol, PHP won't trigger an error. Hence Laravel handleError won't be invoked. Apart from this, you should not change the code in vendor directory as a best practice (also your changes might be lost when you update dependencies using composer). In case you have to then create your own error handler and override the laravel handler.